# How to extract raw sample values from audio file on Android

Tags: android

i am fairly new to android, i wanted to make a function that can open up an audio file '.mp3' or any other android supported format and read its samples , and store it in an array for future processing and etc.
Can anyone help me out.

Thank You...

Comment: What You Have Tried So Far ?

Comment: What do you mean with samples? because on the Amiga a sample is a sound, and several of these samples make a **structured** "module" (ProTracker). An mp3 file is an **unorganized** sequence of **raw bits of sound** (it is a **single waveform**). So, "sample" (for me) is a bit **misleading**.

Comment: Thank you for your response, by samples here i **meant raw bit of sound which represent the sound intensity in individual channel at an instant of time** .

Comment: @RajeshCp , i have tried to unpack the mp3 , but i didnt actually get it right in the first place , so i dont know if that approach was right or wrong.....

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But In android there is no API to do like this. But in Jelly bean they added new API to extract raw samples of audio or video file. Please go through following docs. You will get some idea.
**[MEDIA ExTRACTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html)**. **[MEDIA CoDEC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)**.After processing to playback audio you need to use **[AUDIO TrACK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)**. **[example using above API](https://vec.io/posts/android-hardware-decoding-with-mediacodec)**